# What is the period of $f(2x)$ if $f(2x+6) = f(2x)$ and that of $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, functions, periodic-functions

The question is in the title. Also note that $f(x)$ is **non-constant function**.

This is not same as other question asked from similar title.

I understand that if I put $x+3$ in place of $x$ in $f(2x)$, I get the same function. So the period must be $3$.
And that the period of $f(x)$ must be $6$.

But 'The book' says period of $f(2x)$ is $6$ and of $f(x)$ is $12$.
I cannot understand this.

Comment: Obviously the fundamental period. I also know that if $P$ is period then any integer multiple of it is also period. The question asks for lowest possible Period.

Comment: You are correct. But we are not given enough information to find the fundamental period. For all we know $f$ could be constant.

Comment: @Jyrki so we can say that 3 is one of periods of $f(2x)$ ??

Comment: we can conclude that $6$ is a period of the function $f$. However with only this information we dont know if it is it minimum period.

Comment: I know that, but we can atleast say 6 is one of period of $f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, in finding the **fundamental** period of the function.

Therefore, if you have found the fundamental period of $f(x)$ is $6$, there is no harm in saying that it has a period of $12$, too.

<sub>(Although I understand that when nothing is specified, then we assume that the question is about fundamental period, but if it's a MCQ question and you have no other option that is correct, than this must be the most correct option.)</sub>

Comment: Lowest number which can be called period is ask.

Comment: Thank you you answer it nicely.So we can say surely that one of the period of $f(2x)$ is 3 right?

Comment: @akhmeteni Yup!

Comment: thank you jaideep khare

Comment: You're Welcome @akhmeteni!

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(x)$ clearly has period $6$ because you have an equation of the form $f(y)=f(y+6)$ - whether this is the smallest, or fundamental, period of the function depends on the wording of the question.

For $f(2x)$ - since there seem to have been one or two confused comments - it is perhaps as well to study $g(x)=f(2x)$ and determine the period of $g(x)$. We have, as you have noted $$g(x+3)=f(2x+6)=f(2x)=g(x)$$ and the period is $3$ (or $r=3/n$ for $n$ a positive integer).

Comment: thank you mark bennet.